# How to extend the input field to 100% of the dialog width?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile 1.3 and have some trouble with the style of a popup dialog. 
The dialog is shown below:

[image]

The html code is shown here after:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="AddingDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:500px;" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Modify Item</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Adding new item</h3>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain"  >
            <input type="text" name="name" id="addItemInput" placeholder="label of new item" maxlength="100" value=""  />
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back"
            data-theme="b" data-transition="flow" id="doAddItem">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wished the dialog was wider, that the input field extends to the full width of the dialog, and that the buttons were align right.

Exploring with Firefox developper tools (Examiner) I see that somewhere 78% width is defined. But I don't know how to remove this limitation. I'm also not very excited by this blue shadow showing up when the input field is clicked and that remains there when it is deselected.

I'm not an expert with CSS programming with jQuery mobile.

Comment: check this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qq9Wj/ for the blue shadow, i'll get you with an answer.

Comment: Excellent! The problem was apparently this div data-rol="fieldcontain". I now am able to have a large field by setting size=40 attribute to the input field. Was is left to solve are the button precise positioning and removing the blue halo.

Comment: I forgot to remove the data-inline="true". After removing it and setting the style min-width of the data-role popup tag to the desired width it is now perfect. The only problem left is the halo, but this is not a big problem. Thank you very much. Where could I find a documentation on these ui-grid-X and ui-block-X classes ?

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to remove textbox blue shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

In order to remove the textbox shadow, you need to override JQM CSS `ui-focus`.

Add the below style after JQM stylesheet to override it.

```
.ui-input-text.ui-focus {
 -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Here's the final look of the **[popup](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Qq9Wj/2/)**.

Jquery mobile has a built-in grid system, which facilitate positioning and aligning page's contents. Here is the link to JQM documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: The div data-role="fieldcontain" was taken from a popup example given in the 1.2.0 documentation. I thought it was required. Thank you very much. The focus halo was removed. Great answer. Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I`m glad I`ve been of help :) @chmike